# 'group' only contiguous data

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have folloving data

**Table t1:**

```
╔════╦═════════╦══════════════════╗
║ id ║ name    ║        dt        ║
╠════╬═════════╬══════════════════╣
║  1 ║  name1  ║ 05/05/2016 10:00 ║
║  2 ║  name2  ║ 07/05/2016 10:00 ║
║  3 ║  name1  ║ 08/05/2016 10:00 ║
║  4 ║  name1  ║ 09/05/2016 10:00 ║
╚════╩═════════╩══════════════════╝
```

and i want 'group it by order'  or mark every 'continuous' group with same name

so something like that

```
╔════════╦════════════════════════════════╦══════════════════════════════╦════════╗
║ name   ║ min dt                         ║ max dt                       ║ agg id ║
╠════════╬════════════════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════╬════════╣
║ name1  ║ 05/05/2016 10:00               ║ 05/05/2016 10:00             ║  {1}   ║
║ name2  ║ 07/05/2016 10:00               ║ 07/05/2016 10:00             ║  {2}   ║
║ name1  ║ 08/05/2016 10:00               ║ 09/05/2016 10:00             ║  {3,4} ║
╚════════╩════════════════════════════════╩══════════════════════════════╩════════╝
```

or something like that

```
╔═══════════╦════╦═════════╦══════════════════╗
║ group id  ║ id ║ name    ║        dt        ║
╠═══════════╬════╬═════════╬══════════════════╣
║         1 ║  1 ║  name1  ║ 05/05/2016 10:00 ║
║         2 ║  2 ║  name2  ║ 07/05/2016 10:00 ║
║         3 ║  3 ║  name1  ║ 08/05/2016 10:00 ║
║         3 ║  4 ║  name1  ║ 09/05/2016 10:00 ║
╚═══════════╩════╩═════════╩══════════════════╝
```

is it somehow possible to do in postgres 9.4?

thx michal

Comment: ok, 'contiguous ' was the word that i was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses `lag()` to see if the name has changed.  Then do a cumulative sum of that value:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when name = prev_name then 0 else 1 end) over (order by dt) as grp
from (select t.*,
             lag(name) over (order by dt) as prev_name
      from t1 t
     ) t;
```

For aggregating to get the minimum and maximum, I prefer the difference of row numbers approach:

```
select name, min(dt), max(dt)
from (select t.*,
             (row_number() over (order by dt) - 
              row_number() over (partition by name order by dt)
             ) as grp 
      from t1 t
     ) t
 group by grp, name;
```

To understand what is happening, it is best to run the subquery with the separate row numbers.  In my experience, when you see the sequences and their differences, you'll have an "aha" moment.

Comment: thnx a lot
a think that 
 **select t.*,
             (row_number() over (order by dt) - 
              row_number() over (partition by name order by dt)
             ) as group_id 
      from t1 t**
is exactly what i need
and yes, there was some 'aha' moment how simply genius is that
mk

Comment: Probably not the case for this question, but be carefull if you have repeat dates. Because can cause some weird result. As I just realize trying to get the "aha" moment. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a896e7/1